# PDF not recognize Gujarati Font which is i used in Crystal report (arial-unicode-ms) MVC Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, model-view-controller, unicode, crystal-reports

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiUJ9.png)]

Gujarati font not recognize when PDF download. I used Crystal report for generate PDF.Its work perfectly on Local machine but issue occurred after Hosting site.

Please anyone help me ..... that why this issue occurred.

i did below things.

1. generate again publish code and host.
2. install font on server machine.
   3)add assembly in web.conf file for crystal report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.
I uninstall arial unicode ms.ttf from server and install again by choosing 'Install for all user' option and then It's work.